# Unable to use ALIASES in subquery inside SQL Select clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to use an alias inside a subquery in a select statement like the one below:

```
SELECT 
     InvoiceId,
     InvoiceTotal,
     (SELECT 
       AVG(InvoiceTotal)
       FROM Invoices) AS InvoiceAverage,
     InvoiceTotal - (SELECT InvoiceAverage)
FROM Invoices;
```

When I try to execute the query I get this error:

> 'Invalid column name 'InvoiceAverage'.

Comment: This looks very strange, I think you should provide sample input and expected outcome to make sure you get a correct answer.

Comment: Side note: you've tagged [[tag:correlated-subquery]] here, however, the subquery you have is *not* correlated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for a subquery here, use windowed aggregates:

```sql
SELECT InvoiceId,
       InvoiceTotal,
       AVG(InvoiceTotal) OVER () AS InvoiceAverage,
       InvoiceTotal - AVG(InvoiceTotal) OVER () AS YourAliasGoesHere
FROM dbo.Invoices;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may directly minus the sub query value from `InvoiceTotal` as

```
SELECT 
     InvoiceId,
     InvoiceTotal,
     (SELECT AVG(InvoiceTotal) FROM Invoices) AS InvoiceAverage,
     (InvoiceTotal - (SELECT AVG(InvoiceTotal) FROM Invoices)) AS InvoiceCalculatedValue
FROM Invoices;
```

or you may store the AVG value in a variable and use in the select query

```
DECLARE @InvoiceAverage AS DECIMAL (18,2) = 0;
SELECT @InvoiceAverage = AVG(InvoiceTotal) FROM Invoices;

SELECT 
     InvoiceId,
     InvoiceTotal,
     @InvoiceAverage AS InvoiceAverage
     (InvoiceTotal - @InvoiceAverage) AS InvoiceCalculatedValue
FROM Invoices;
```